# How to connect raspberry pi to internet?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, debian

Here i have connected my raspberry pi to my laptop using the ethernet cable.
Inside the raspberry pi boot SD card i have opened the file cmdline and added the following information at the end of the file.

```
ip=169.254.1.1
```

Now i have connected my raspberry pi to the laptop using the ethernet cable and used putty to connect to this device by using the ip address 169.254.1.1 and port 22 using SSH.

Everything is working fine , i have accesed the file system.
But now i wanted to access the intenet so i have entered the command

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect:Network in unreachable
```

How to access to the internet?How to approach this problem?Any suggestions.

Tutorial followed : [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ioih6MHNNqc)

Comment: Why not connect the Pi to a network that provides Internet access rather than to your laptop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i wanted to connect to my laptop where i wanted to download some git files and then run using ssh

Comment: Then you'll need to configure your laptop to share its Internet connection. What OS is your laptop using?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Windows 10

Comment: Punch "internet connection sharing" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you need is called "Internet Connection Sharing". From the Network and Sharing Center, select "Change Adapter Settings". Select your Internet connection and pull up its properties page. Click on the "Sharing" tab. Check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection". Select the network interface that connects to the Pi as the interface to share on.